# Meta API for getting the long-lived token showing Sorry, this content isn't available right now

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have called the Instagram Meta API for getting the long-lived token. It generates a response like

> Sorry, this content isn't available right now

```
https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret={instagram-app-secret}&access_token={short-lived-access-token}
```

This is the API which I used for getting the long-lived token.

FYI - I'm using the test app.

I have tried calling the meta API for getting the long-lived token but I couldn't get it.

Comment: Can you point to the documentation that you are basing this on, please?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently when I was trying to use the Instagram Graph API. I could exchange a valid short-lived token by a long-lived one using the following endpoint ([documentation reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/?locale=en))

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=${app_id}&client_secret=${app_secret}&fb_exchange_token=${short_lived_access_token}"
```

With the corresponding environment variables `app_id`, `app_secret`, and `short_lived_access_token` defined previousuly.

I hope it helps